# How to create separate rows for each unique value in source data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following table:

```
Cus_ID  Work_Phone     Home_Phone     Mobile_Phone
1       x              Blank          x
2       x              x              Blank
3       x              x              x
.
.
. and so on (1000s of rows)
```

Work_Phone, Home_Phone, Mobile_Phone - varchar

x = some value present

I need to select from Source data to move it Target system like below,  I need to create separate row for unique values for each Cus_ID.  How do i do it?

```
Cus_ID    Type      ContactNo
1         Work       x
1         Mobile     x
2         Work       x
2         Home       x
3         Work       x
3         Home       x
3         Mobile     x

.. and so on
```

Type, ContactNo - varchar

x = Should be the corresponding value from Source table

Comment: Sorry guys for not being so detail earlier, I edited to include much more detail of the problem.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `col1`, `col2` and `col3` are of the same type, then:

```
SELECT pk, col2 AS target_value FROM your_table WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT pk, col3 AS target_value FROM your_table WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT pk, col4 AS target_value FROM your_table WHERE col4 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY pk
```

Edit edit: here's the version with `ISNULL` tests, column headings and the rest, in response to your revised question:

```
SELECT Cus_ID, 'Work' AS Type, Work_Phone AS ContactNo FROM your_table
   WHERE ISNULL(Work_Phone, '') <> ''
UNION 
SELECT Cus_ID, 'Home' AS Type, Home_Phone AS ContactNo FROM your_table
   WHERE ISNULL(Home_Phone, '') <> ''
UNION
SELECT Cus_ID, 'Mobile' AS Type, Mobile_Phone AS ContactNo FROM your_table
   WHERE ISNULL(Mobile_Phone, '') <> ''
ORDER BY 1
```

If there's a chance the "blank" column may contain whitespace characters, then refine it yet further to:

```
... ISNULL(LTRIM(Work_Phone), '') <> ''
```

etc.

Comment: What dupes? But you're right, the ALL is unnecessary (though harmless). I've corrected the code. Thanks.

Comment: See newly edited answer. Hope that's enough. I've used ISNULLs to allow for 'blank' phone numbers to be *either* null *or* blank, without breaking.

Comment: I achieved the results by using your updated query . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

above result we can achieve using UNPIVOT or Cross Apply also by basing on your assumed data

```
declare @t table (PK varchar(1),col1 varchar(1),col2 varchar(1),col3 varchar(1))
      insert into @t(PK,col1,col2,col3)values 
        ('X','a','','c'),
        ('y','a','b',''),
        ('z','a','b','c')
```

**Cross Apply :**

```
select PK,value
from @t
cross apply
(
    values
        ('I1', col1),
        ('I2', col2),
        ('I3', col3)
) c(col, value)
where value is not null AND value <> ''
order by PK, col
```

**UNPIVOT**

```
select PK,value
from @t
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (col1, col2, col3)
) un
WHERE value <> ''
order by PK, col;
```